# Debug a huge memory leak which freezes the computer (C++)

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-leaks

My application has a huge memory leak which eats all my memory instantly, and I can't debug as it freezes the computer ...
Do you guys have any technical solution for that kind of issue?
Edit : I am using Qt Creator with Windows 7 and MSVC compiler.
Cheers

Comment: Kinda hard to debug something when you've provided no code whatsoever.

Comment: if your using new operator you should have delete operator too. On g++ or gcc you should use debugging command line args like -g or -Wall or maybe get valgrind...

Comment: Its an application of 100k lines of code, I am just asking for a general solution to be able to debug it by preventing the computer from freezing.

Comment: `Do you guys have any technical solution for that kind of issue`  Yes.  Use your debugger. `I can't debug as it freezes the computer`.  A debugger doesn't start the program "on its own".  You have total control over when it starts, where to place the breakpoints, etc.

Comment: You don't give us any details about what your program is doing, what compiler, what operating system..

Comment: Without details you won't get any meaningful answers, and no one else - in the future - will benefit from your question either. That is why it is downvoted, and flagged as "too borad".

Comment: @Neil : sorry about that. MSVC 2013 with Qt Creator on Windows 7. My program is basically making some calculation to output vector of numbers.

Comment: You know.... *every* application is basically crunching some numbers and outputting it to a vector of some kind....

Comment: @Cygnus : I am sorry, its true that I didn't provide enough information, my apologies.

Comment: @Cygnus : it is an audio application which calculates oscillators with effetcts, mixes them, etc ...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just freeze a computer with a single instruction. If you allocate a lot of memory, it will either crash the program or use a virtual memory space without actually consuming the real space.

Thus, if you debug it further, maybe in smaller steps, I am sure you will find your solution.

There are many debugging tools that you can try to use, depending on your working environment. Assuming you are working under linux, the simplest one is the command line `gdb`, allowing you to execute code line-by-line. More advanced, tailored specifically to memory problems is `valgrind`.

---

In the comment you are asking if there is a way for the OS to artifically limit the available memory to a program/process. You can try by reading this question:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

however, given the little information you provided, I am not convinced it will solve your problem.

Comment: Cygnus, you are right, it uses virtual memory which has the same result in pratice !

Comment: Taking a huge chunk of virtual memory, without doing anything with it yet won't freeze your system.

Comment: It doesn't freeze it technically, but nothing is responding except the movement of the mouse.

Comment: maybe valgrind would be helpful to suggest...

Comment: I just need to force my program not to use all the memory available, but I have no idea if thats is possible ...

Comment: @Cygnus: I use Qt Creator on windows with MSVC 2013

Comment: Now, that is a vital piece of information you didn't provide! I know nothing of Qt Creator. MSVC has a good built-in debugger though. You should be able to narrow the problem down. But with the little information you provide, there is hard to give you any meaningful hints besides that.

Comment: -7. Thats encouraging thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have got global variables which allocate memory immediately, i.e. before reaching the first line of code in `main()`, which could be found for instance in class constructors, then you may consider placing your breakpoints not on the first line of `main()` but rather on the class constructors. Just as a hint based on a previous similar experience ...